# Access a variable outside a for-loop Swift

Tags: ios, variables, swift, range

I am trying to access "numOne" right before the return statement and I can't seem to find why it is not working. Everything was fine accessing "numTwo". Is the reason because "numOne" is inside a range?

```
func checknumber() -> String {
    var numTwo = 0
    var range = 0...b
    for numOne in range {
        numTwo = b-numOne
        if let result = isCommon(numOne: numOne, numTwo: numTwo) {
            println("Success - \(numOne) and \(numTwo) Work")

            break
        } else {
            println("Failure - \(numOne) and \(numTwo) Does NOT Work")
        }
        var numOneFinal = numOne
    }

    var numberTwo = "\(numTwo)"
    var numberOne = "\(numOneFinal)"

    return numberTwo
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numOne` is scoped by the `for` statement in which it is defined.

To gain access to the last value of `numOne` after the loop, add a new variable, say `numOneFinal`, at the same level as `numTwo`, then assign `numOne`'s value to it within the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I did what you said but I am getting an "Use of unresolved identifier 'numOneFinal' error. What am I doing wrong? I have update my code in the question to show you what I am doing

Comment: You need to declare the new variable, same as you have `numTwo` above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access numOne outside of the for loop, because it's out of the scope. You can only access numOne within the loop